# Adding values in Linked-List Calculator

Tags: c, parsing, linked-list

I am working on a single linked-list calculator in C (yes, it's homework). I have the add functions "working" but for some reason I can only add two values that are the same length. I can't really figure out how to add something like 12 + 128. Currently my code only accepts 120 + 128. What did I do wrong, how can I fix this code?

```
struct digit* add(struct digit *x, struct digit *y)
{
    int carry = 0;
    struct digit *xHead;
    struct digit *yHead;
    struct digit *totalHead;
    struct digit *current_Digit;

    xHead = x;
    yHead = y;
    totalHead = NULL;


    while(x != NULL && y != NULL)
    {
        current_Digit = (struct digit *)malloc(sizeof(struct digit));
        current_Digit->value = x->value + y->value + carry;

        //calculates the carry
        carry = 0;
        if(current_Digit->value > 9)
        {
            carry = 1;
            current_Digit->value = current_Digit->value % 10;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
        current_Digit->next = totalHead;
        totalHead = current_Digit;

        x = x->next;
        y = y->next;
    }
    return totalHead;
}
```

Comment: what does your `struct digit` look like?

Comment: struct digit
{
   int value; //data
   struct digit *next; //next pointer
};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going to `x->next` and `y->next` simultaneously, your function should do the following:

```
while (x != NULL || y != NULL) {
    // malloc

    current_Digit->value = (x ? x->value : 0)
                         + (y ? y->value : 0)
                         + carry;

    // compute

    if (x) x = x->next;
    if (y) y = y->next;
}
```

(It also looks as if you're constructing your result list backwards...)

Comment: when I do it this way. 120 + 100 = 120. 100 + 120 = 100. Sorry, I am really new to this stuff and this "simple" issue is giving me a headache! Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @user706553: I forgot some parentheses. Can you check again?

Comment: @user706553 You seem to be building `totalHead` right-to-left, which is the opposite way you're reading `x` and `y`. Ie, your input looks like `8->2->1` but your output is constructed as `1->2->8` for the number 128.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently incrementing the digits of both arguments without looking at whether you've hit the end of one of them. You need to have a special test that if only one linked list is at its end, then don't increment it and just assume its digit value is zero.

So `12 + 128` should be dynamically made as `[0]12 + 128`. You must add logic to recognize that the `x` value in this case has reached the end of its digits but the `y` has not. So keep going with the `y` and conjure zero for the `x` digit.

Comment: Just to clarify, that special test case would be outside the while loop which checks for both of them to hit NULL right?

Comment: @user706553 The test is in the while loop. Check @larsman for the sample code.

Comment: deleted my post, undid the -1. It indeed looks like the OP is building the result backwards, which may or may not be intended.

Comment: @chrissaycock: yeah, tried his method but I am running into problems there as well. @larsmans whenever I insert a new number I make that the head, therefore it is built backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure `x` and `y` have the same number of digits, otherwise you'll end up with either set to `NULL`. Before adding, find the shortest and add zeros to it until you match the other's length